# Maven Aggregrator Without Inheritance Dilemma

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar

Update: I've rephrased the question as the problem is now correctly identified as Maven aggregator without inheritance.

Basically I have three projects with the outline is as:

Parent - core (jar format)
Child1 -> API (web application with core jar)
Child2 -> batch (runnable jar with core jar)

Each of the three components above are separate projects.

For child1 project, I noticed that jar dependency appears twice, but in separate folders, with one appearing at WEB-INF/lib and another at WEB-INF/classes/lib. Hence the war size is bloated and I want only the libraries (for child 1 and those required by parent) to appear only once.

Sorry, I am bit blur in Maven, but I need a bit of help in where have I missed out that needs to be changed in the pom.xml files.

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry I can't read images here..please add text instead of image links..

Comment: you run against the java classloader here - it does not support loading jar files from within other jar files. Spring Boot for example follows the same approach to not unpack/repack dependent jar files. It uses a maven plugin to create an uber jar and a custom class loader to load the packaged jars as well. That might be the way to go.

Comment: @khmarbaise - I've put in a text there as for convenience.

Comment: I just saw another third-party plugin, which I just tested, and it came the closest to the intended result. It's called the Capsule Maven Plugin: [link]https://github.com/chrisdchristo/capsule-maven-plugin [/link]